# How to position bootstrap popover inside grid column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 alpha 6.

Here is a grid with one row and two columns, the first containing a text, and the second a popover:

```
<div class="row text-center align-items-center" style="height:200px;background-color:grey">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <span>This text is centered horizontally and vertically.</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="popover popover-right">
      <h3 class="popover-title">Popover left</h3>
      <div class="popover-content">
        <p>But how to vertically center and right align this popover in the second column?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I have the popover vertically centered and horizontally right aligned in its column?

I created this codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/8VQbV5khtO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these css propeties style to your popup div

```
.popover {
    /** add below prop**/
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.popover.popover-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.popover.popover-left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't right align (only centers). Also wonder if there is a bootstrap way of doing this alignment?

Comment: See my updated answer ,  it align both right and left , if not .popover-* class , its gonna be in the center :)